# Trouble installing kivy in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I tried to install kivy in python 3.9 using multiple commands as well as browsing stackoverflow for similar questions, but the answers for them didn't work for me unfortunately.. and it resulted with the same error:

```
    command: 'c:\users\USER\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, 
    setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
    4wyhedmd\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
    4wyhedmd\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
    (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
    '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-duetikli'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4wyhedmd\kivy\
```

And then this:

```
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

> the error message is bigger than this, I just reached character limits

Comment: As far as I know, Kivy does not yet support python 3.9, it officially supports 3.6 and lower, and it worked good for me on 3.7.

Comment: Try installing `kivy` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy).

Comment: @Yuval.R Gohlke has a wheel on the link above for 3.9, so I would assume it works there.